# How to access the link of a listitem

Tags: watin

I know there is proably an obvious anwser to this question but I'm trying to learn WatiN and can't figure it out my self :(.

My problem is i need to click a ListItem but i can't get it working as I'd like.

```
HTML:
<ul class="pageNavigation">
<li><a href="/users/dashboard">&#187; Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="/users">&#187; Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="/accounts/settings">&#187; Settings</a></li>
```

**What I'm doing:**

```
ListItem list = ie.List(Find.ByClass("pageNavigation")).ListItem(Find.ByIndex(1));
ie.Link(Find.ByText(list.ToString())).Click();
```

**What I would like to be doing:**
Instead of getting the ListItem text i would like to get the ListItem href.

**NOTE:**
`ie.List(Find.ByClass("pageNavigation")).ListItem(Find.ByIndex(1)).Click();` doesn't work it just clicks the list item area and not the actual link.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it might help if you try to click the link itself:

```
ie.List(Find.ByClass("pageNavigation")).ListItem(Find.ByIndex(1)).Links[0].Click();
```

OR

```
ie.List(Find.ByClass("pageNavigation")).ListItem(Find.ByIndex(1)).Link(Find.Any).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i couldn't figure out :)